# nest start removes my json files from dist

Tags: typescript, nestjs, yarnpkg

when I build my nestjs application, I need certain json files to be copied to the dist. especially I have an "engines" folder, and I need the json files to be on dist/and prod, as they are in src/engines.

However, nest start removes the dist folder and recreates with only d.ts, js and js.map, and my json files are removed.

I tried to do the following in my `package.json` `scripts`:

```
"copy:json": "copyfiles -u 2 src/engines/**/*.json dist/engines",
"start": "nest start && yarn copy:json",
"start:dev": "nest start --watch && yarn copy:json",
"start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch && yarn copy:json",
"start:prod": "node dist/main && yarn copy:json",
```

I don't know why, but when I do start:dev, I still have any *json* file in my `dist` directory.
The `yarn copy:json` alone works well (copies the right files in the right location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the `*.json` files to the assets, which get copied on build.

eg. in your `nest-cli.json`:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "assets": ["engines/**/*.json"],
    "watchAssets": true
  }
```

[Source](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#assets)